# Original fileURL from ItemProvider and UIDropInteractionDelegate functions

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

Our iOS application allows users to select an email attachment document and upload it, through our application, to a remote database on a cloud server.  We have been doing this successfully using "open in..", which allows us to identify the current fileURL of the document. Using the fileURL, we can both display the document in our application for immediate use, as well as upload it in the background to the remote data base.  All good and very fast from a user perspective.

However, on iPad in split-screen mode, we would now also like to allow drag-and-drop, where the user drags the attachment from their email program and drops it on our application.  Item Providers are used for this purpose, along with the UIDropInteractionDelegate methods.  Unfortunately, these methods seem to want to either copy or move the document, rather than provide us with the existing fileURL.  Moving or copying and then uploading the document into our application are both slow and expensive in CPU processing and thus degrade the user experience. We don't want to do anything with the file on the device.  All we want is to get the existing fileURL.  We will take it from there!

Question: How can we find the existing fileURL of a "dropped" document, using the Item Provider and the UIDropInteractionDelegate methods?

Comment: Some ideas - check for a `public.url` type identifier. Use the `loadFileRepresentation` or `loadInPlaceFileRepresentation` methods of `NSItemProvider`.

Comment: Agree with rmaddy, loadInPlaceFileRepresentation seems like it would be a good suggestion.  Unfortunately, the fileURL that loadInPlaceFileRepresentation presents appears to be located in /tmp/.com.apple.Foundation.NSItemProvider/, rather than in the original /Documents/Inbox/.  The NSItemProvider location contains no data, unless we go to the, seemingly unnecessary and not insignificant, extra work of uploading the data from its original location.  Thoughts?

Comment: I was able to get this problem solved with the help of an Apple engineer. Item Providers do not allow access to to the original fileURL. loadFileRepresentation and loadInPlaceFileRepresentation provide short-lived access to the dragged document, allowing it to be dropped in a new location.  They both use a temporary file directory location that is removed at completion of closure.  To use the file for upload or immediate display, you need to save it to another directory of your choosing before leaving the closure.  Works perfectly!

Comment: @oldCoder you're a life-saver !!!

Comment: @oldCoder But how to do that?

Comment: What part of the above explanation are you looking for assistance implementing?